# Detected output overflow in Quarto to pdf conversion

Tags: pdf, r-markdown, rstudio, knitr, quarto

In my Quarto background console runing in Rstudio the conversion to pdf is blocked before the end and this message appears:

```
[detected output overflow; 
buffering the next 5000 lines of output]
```

How to get rid of it?

I tried to increase the output limit in `Tools > Global Options > Console` and changing the `"Limit output to console"` setting to a higher value. This not worked.

Comment: Check whether you are unknowingly printing a very large data frame.

Comment: There is no large data frame printing in this part. It stopped at 64% so I cut the script in 2 parts and I got two pdf files generated correctly. The first one is 256 pages and the other 178. It's just strange knowing that a pdf can be very larger thant that.